# I've successfully deployed a MVC3 website on windows azure but it didn't work

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, azure

I've made a free trial account on Windows Azure and I tried to deploy one of my MVC 3 projects. On my account on Windows Azure the website status is "running" and the database is "online". The deploy was successfully, but when I go to the URL, nothing happens.

Why is that?

URL: http://productsellingpage.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: nslookup isn't resolving the URL for me, if you set up a new site and don't deploy anything, just create it, what happens.

Comment: DNS isn't resolving "azurewebsites.net" or "productsellingpage.azurewebsites.net"

Answer (score 0):

When a Windows Azure Websites is created but nothing is deployed, opening the URL in a browser return the following page:
[image]

I could verify that the websites URL you provided is already registered with Windows Azure Websites so it is a correct URL and because it does not show the placeholder page as seen in above image, so I am sure something is deployed to this website.

Your best bet is to contact Windows Azure Websites team directly from dedicated forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads).

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog helpful to publishing via Visual Studio

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/26/deploying-windows-azure-website-using-visual-studio-web-publish-wizard.aspx

But the publish tool direct from Visual Studio can be unreliable so I have resorted to upload via direct FTP. The host name of the site will be in the right hand pane of your website details.